# optimization using "nlminb"

Tags: r

im now performing Location Model using non-parametric smoothing to estimate the paramneters.....one of the smoothed paramater is the lamdha that i have to optimize...

so in that case, i decide to use "nlminb function" to achieve it.....

however, my programing give me the same "$par" value even though it was iterate 150 time and make 200 evaluation (by default)..... which is it choose "the start value as $par" (that is 0.000001 ...... i think, there must be something wrong with my written program....

my programing look like:-   (note: w is the parameter that i want to optimize and LOO is 
                              stand for leave-one-out

BEGIN

```
Myfunc <- function(w, n1, n2, v1, v2, g)
{  ## open  loop for main function

## DATA generation
        # generate data from group 1 and 2
        # for each group: discretise the continuous to binary
        # newdata <- combine the groups 1 and 2

## MODEL construction
     countError <- 0
        n <- nrow(newdata)

       for (k in 1:n)
       {# open loop for leave-one-out
             # construct model based on n-1 object using smoothing method
                 # classify omitted object
                countError <- countError + countE
       }   # close loop for LOO process

          Error <- countError / n     # error rate counted from LOO procedure 

     return(Error)           # The Average ERROR Rate from LOO procedure 

}       # close loop for Myfunc

library(stats)
  nlminb(start=0.000001, Myfunc, lower=0.000001, upper=0.999999, 
                 control=list(eval.max=100, iter.max=100))
```

END

could someone help me......

your concerns and guidances is highly appreciated and really100 needed......

Hashibah,
Statistic PhD Student

Answer (score 3):

In your question, provide a `nlminb` with a univariate starting value. If you are doing *univariate* optimisation, it is probably worth looking at `optimize`. If your function is *multivariate*, then you need to call `nlminb` slightly differently.

You need define the objective function such that you provide the parameters to optimize over as a vector which is the first argument. Other inputs to the objective function should be provided as subsequent arguments.

For example (modified from the `nlminb` help page):

```
X <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10)
hdev <- function(par, x) {
 -sum(dnbinom(x, mu = par[1], size = par[2], log = TRUE))
}
nlminb(start = c(9, 12), hdev, x = X)
```